# AWS EC2 NTP Server - user data edit prefer ntp ips

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ntp

In EC2 instance under user data.
How do I set that it
sudo vi etc/chrony.conf

and remove the default ntp server and add in my prefer servers?

Comment: sed -i '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\This line is removed by the admin.' /tmp/foo

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-match-replace-the-entire-line-command/

```
sed -i '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\This line is removed by the admin.' /tmp/foo.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (considering your preferred IP is "169.254.169.123").

```
# Adding Amazon Time Sync Service to Chrony
sed -e '/^server / s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/chrony.conf
echo -e "server 169.254.169.123 iburst" >> /etc/chrony.conf
sudo service chronyd restart
```